# UITabBar focus and moving layout of view on tvOS

Tags: focus, uitabbarcontroller, tvos, apple-tv

One of the common behaviours of Apple's AppleTV apps (like Movies and Television Shows) is that they start with a UITabBar visible, and all of the view's content is rendered in the space below the tab bar. Once focus moves from the tab bar to some content on the screen, the tab bar slides off the top of the screen, and the content moves/scrolls up to fill in the space that's now available. This process reverses itself if the tab bar reappears.

Is there an easy way to accomplish this behaviour (like a check box or something?), or must I implement the `didUpdateFocusInContext:withAnimationCoordinator:` method in various places, and manually tweak the frames or scroll the content or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select the Tab Bar object in the Tab Bar Controller scene in Storyboard mode and uncheck "Translucent". The items in the views should now move upwards when the tab bar moves upwards.

The UITabBar class also has a `translucent` property

Comment: Aha! Perfect. Thanks!

Comment: Hm. It seems to work fine if my tab bar controller directly contains the view controller, but if there's a Navigation Controller in between, then it doesn't work. Sad.

Comment: @bcholmes I realize this comes a little late, but you can put your navigation controller in a UIViewController and add that UIViewController as one of the tab bars view controller.